# Basic motor principles

Tags: motor

If a tube shaped permanent magnet with circular magnetic field was introduced in to another external magnetic field, would a force act at right angles as it would a copper wire with DC voltage applied?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you think you'd construct "a tube shaped permanent magnet with circular magnetic field", but like a horseshoe magnet with a "keeper bar" across its ends, such an object would have very little external magnetic field — the field would mostly be contained in the closed ferromagnetic path.

Just like any other ferromagnetic object, it would experience an attractive force toward any other source of a magnetic field. Orientation ("at right angles"?) would have little, if anything, to do with it.

If you're thinking you can construct a perpetual motion machine this way, forget it. In order to get continuous rotation, you need to be able to switch the magnetic field on and off, which is why we do it with electricity and coils of wire.

Comment: Continuous rotation can be achieved without switching, it's called a Homopolar motor which was the first electrical motor to be built and required no commutator.

Comment: @StevenCarr: I wondered whether anyone would bring up homopolar designs. It doesn't require a commutator in the usual sense, but it does require a sliding contact, which is a kind of "continuous commutation".

Comment: Commutation is to change or reverse, you are referring to brushes which are the sliding contact, this is not commutation.

Comment: All right, I'm not going to argue with you. How does this relate to your original question?

Comment: I have never come across a permanent magnet manufactured the way I mentioned in the original question. I have been looking for further insight. You mentioned the attractive force to the external magnets and this is something I have looked at, the attraction can be overcome when placed exactly central between the external north and south poles, this creates a net zero attraction leaving the internal field to interact with the external.